# Which politician is lying

Tags: logic

Five politicians make the following statements:

Anna: 'Charles and Dumisani are lying'

Ben: 'Anna and Ellie are lying'

Charles : 'Ben and Dumisani are lying'

Dumisani : 'Charies and Ellie are lying'

Ellie : 'Anna and Ben are lying'.

Which politician is definitely lying?

When I attempted the question using logic, I first split the problem into cases where each politician is assumed to be telling the truth and determined which of the other politicians were lying in each given case. Eventually, I realized that Anna was lying in 4 of the cases however, in the Case were Anna was telling the truth, I eventually arrived at a contradiction so it led me to believe that Anna is definitely lying in this given problem. My main issue with this is that my solution was too long and I have no way of knowing if it's even correct so I wanted to get some opinions on this

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9201), so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Post edit:  I agree with you that Anna is clearly lying, and I don't think the argument for that is terribly hard...  But I did not check all the others, which does look a bit tedious.  Again, not actually hard, but I don't see a quick way to settle the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to use formal logic to help solve this problem.

First, use $A$ to symbolize "Anna is telling the truth", and analogously for $B$ through $E$.

Now note that Anna is telling the truth if and only if what she is saying is true. So, we can capture the fat that Anna claims that Charles and Dumisani are lying with the following logic expression:

$$A \leftrightarrow (\neg C \land \neg D)$$

Given Ben's statement, you get:

$$B \leftrightarrow (\neg A \land \neg E)$$

etc.

OK, and now you can use any formal logic method to try and solve this. Personally, I would use a combination of inference and algebra. In particular, you can treat biconditionals as a kind of substitution. For example, you can combine the above two statements to:

$$B \leftrightarrow (\neg (\neg C \land \neg D) \land \neg E)$$

And you can use DeMorgan, Double Negation, etc. to try and simplify.

Now, the above substitution was actually not a very useful one (do you see why?), so make some smart substitutions, and do some further algebra, and you should be able to get to the solution fairly quickly.

Indeed, by following this method I was quickly able to deduce that Anna is definitely lying, and that either Ben and Dumisani are both telling the truth, while Charles and Ellie are both lying, or vice versa, and so you can't say whether any one of them is telling the truth or lying, except for Anna. Try it, it's actually good fun!

Comment: Lovely stuff, I was actually looking for a solution along these lines. Thank you!

Comment: @JohnsonKamanga You're welcome! If you are satisfied with my Answer, you can accept it by clicking on the check mark to the left of it.